# Is my new object instance redefining my this parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

My goal is to establish “this“ as a reference to the button object. I understand that a solution to my problem would be to use an arrow function but Im curious, is the reference to “this“ redefined when creating a new object instance of button? Or is the initial click method not inheriting the “this“ reference to begin with? If it is the latter, then would the “this“ of the click method be the initial button function?

```
<button id=“test“> Click Me! </button>    
    <script>
        function Button( ) {     
            this.clicked = false;  
            this.click = function( ) { 
            this.clicked = true;              
            assert(button.clicked, “The button has been clicked“);             

                };         
      }
        var  button = new Button( ); 
        var  elem = document.getElementById(“test“); 
        elem.addEventListener(“click“, button.click);
```

event listener fails to find click state

Comment: Did you try putting `this.click = this.click.bind(this)` at the end of the `Button function`?  Not sure if you understand that `button.click` is just the unbound function that gets passed to `addEventListener`

Comment: or just `this.click = function() { ... snip ...}.bind(this);`

Comment: @JaromandaX I included your note in my answer, but when using ES6 class syntax, (which is strongly recommended) you'll have to fall back to the first approach of binding in the constructor.

Comment: @Wyck - that's a very good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just pass `button.click` to `addEventListener` then you're just passing the function and it will be called with no `this` context.

So you fix that you have bind the function to the object.

You can either write the following, to bind the click function to the button object as a one-off:

```
elem.addEventListener('click, button.click.bind(button));
```

Or you can permanently bind the click function to the button object by writing the following in the constructor:

```
this.click = this.click.bind(this);
```

Or you could be economical with your syntax and combine them together like the following:

```
this.click = function () {
  // ... your code here ...
}.bind(this);
```

```js
function Button() {
  this.clicked = false;
  this.click = function () {
    console.log(this.secret);
  }.bind(this);
}
var button = new Button();
button.secret = 'It works';
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
elem.addEventListener('click', button.click);
```

```html
<button id="test"> Click Me! </button>
```